# Shifted content in pas-tableur

Tags: tables, pas-tableur

I want to modify the width of the columns in a `pas-tableur`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pas-tableur}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tableur*[2]{A/2cm,B/2cm,C/3cm}
\celtxt {A}{1}{Firma}
\celtxt {B}{1}{Straße}
\celtxt {C}{1}{Ansprechpartner}
\celtxt {A}{2}{\dots}
\celtxt {B}{2}{\dots}
\celtxt {C}{2}{\dots}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But in the output, the content of the first two columns is shifted to the left. The third column is just fine. And I fail to see why.

I wanted to add the tag pas-tableur, but I don't have enough reputation for that.

Comment: Probably your columns are just too narrow for their contents? Something like `\tableur*[2]{A/3.5cm,B/3.5cm,C/4cm}` should result in an improved output.

Comment: hm, if i take the left margin of Firma in a cell that is 3.5 cm, like suggested width, then ia have a lot of free space in that cell. Reducing the cellwidth again to 3 cm shifts the content, which (in my opinion) is not understandable. btw, the contens act funny altogether, by having different margins on the left side, but not being centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the `width=` option for each `\celtxt` item so they match what `\tableur*` has used. Otherwise the default width (7em) is used.

[image: not a spreadsheet]

It's a drawing done using TikZ. A convincingly real drawing. There are no actual spreadsheet columns or rows, just TikZ nodes placing text and drawing things.

Which means there is some scope for using other TikZ commands, like `\fill` and `\draw`, and even adding more `\node`s.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pas-tableur}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%\tabcolwidth{8em}%set width all columns when using \tableur; default width is 7em.
\tableur*[3]{A/2cm,B/2cm,C/4cm}
\celtxt[width=2cm]{A}{1}{Firma}
\celtxt[width=2cm]{B}{1}{Straße}
\celtxt[width=4cm]{C}{1}{Ansprechpartner}
\celtxt*[width=2cm]{A}{2}{$x^2$}%math
\celtxt[width=2cm]{B}{2}{y}
\celtxt[color=red,width=4cm]{C}{2}{z}%colour
\celtxt[r,width=4cm]{C}{3}{=A3*B3}%formula; set alighment in last cell

\selecCell{B}{2}%select a cell

\draw[<-,>=latex] (cellB-2.center) to[bend right=30] ($(cellB-2)+(2,-1.7)$) 
node[right] {C'est la cellule {\helvbx B2}};

%''background'' colour
\fill[green!20,opacity=0.5](cellB-3.north west) --
(cellB-3.north east) --
(cellB-3.south east) --
(cellB-3.south west) --
cycle;
%put some text on top of the fill
\node [xshift=0.5em] at (cellB-3.west) {\helvbx{3}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```